# Database storing the last value of the field

Tags: jquery, laravel

When I am selecting an option from select box, then the value related to it is showing in another input field. Till now, everything is fine. But now, when I store it in database the input value stores the last  value.

Here is my code :

```
<select class="form-control" name="organisation" id="mainpage">
    <option selected="">Select</option>
    @foreach($users as $k=>$u)
    @if($u->created_by == $userId)
    <option value="{{ $u->id }}" id="{{ $u->id }}">{{ $u->name }}</option>
    @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

The below input field stores the last value in database no matter which field is selected in above select box.

```
<div class="form-control" id="mainsection">
    @foreach($users as $k=>$u)
        @if($u->created_by == $userId)
            <input id="{{ $u->user_id }}" data-parent="{{ $u->id }}" value="{{ $u->user_id }}" style="display: none;">                             
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Here is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("select#mainpage").on('change',function () {     
        jQuery("div#mainsection").find('input').css('display', 'none');
        var idclassurl = jQuery("select#mainpage :selected").attr('id')
        jQuery("div#mainsection").find('input[data-parent="'+idclassurl+'"]').css('display', 'block');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where is the store method ?

Comment: its just a part of it.. Its a long form

Comment: Please add store method. So we can check and assist you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var valueToStore, displayedInput;
  jQuery("select#mainpage").on('change',function() {
      valueToStore = null;
      displayedInput = jQuery("div#mainsection").find('input[data-parent="'+idclassurl+'"]');
      displayedInput.css('display', 'block');
      valueToStore = displayedInput.val();
  });
 </script>
```